# Angular 4 ie9 infinite hashbang error on loading site

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-9

I am working on angular 4 version. I have solved almost all the issues coming on the ie9, But redirect hashband issue is not solving.

When I build the app for production passing `ng build --prod --aot` , it does redirection of hashbang like `localhost/myapp/#en/#en....`

IE9 goes infinite if loading a base URL without a trailing slash with hashbangs.

Comment: @georgeawg. Thanks for corrections . Please help me in answer as well. I am stuck in middle